# session_start() returns "No such file or directory" directly after creating the session file

Tags: php, session, iis, permissions, fastcgi

I'm trying to set the session.save_path on my IIS/PHP via fastcgi server.  So I created a new folder called tmp in my php folder, gave IUSR and IIS_IUSRS full permissions to this folder, and set my session.save_path variable in php.ini to "\tmp".

Upon loading my webpage I get the error:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(tmp\sess_gp13t5fg969iddfq1lrt3e88o1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

The weird thing is I know it can see the folder because I look in my newly created tmp folder and it actually created the sess_gp13t5fg969iddfq1lrt3e88o1 file right before throwing the error telling me it doesn't exist.  So how can it create the file and then not see it?  What could I be doing wrong?

**Update:** If I set session.save_path with an absolute path, it works.  When I give it a relative path of just "\tmp" it no longer works.  Every example I see uses a relative path for the save_path and I personally need to use a relative path.  Why would a relative path cause this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: What trouble shooting have you done? It says no such file or directory, so how do you know which one is causing the error? Have you tried opening another file in that directory? Could it be the relative path not finding the folder?

Comment: @GaryHayes Sure enough, if I put the full path to the folder under session.save_path, it works.  However, I really need to use a relative path here because we use the same php.ini file in multiple development workstations where PHP might be installed elsewhere. Why would using a relative path under session.save_path cause this issue and how could I fix it?

Comment: What version of IIS/Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you seek:

[Relative Paths in PHP](http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/)

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/relative path here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Under linux the PrivateTmp config of systemd may be the problem.
The solution would be to copy the corresponding systemd unit file to /etc/systemd and remove there the privatetmp config.
In my case:

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service /etc/systemd/system
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Change in /etc/systemd/httpd.service then

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

to

```
PrivateTmp=false
```